# How to prevent the style of the layout from affecting the content？

Tags: html, css

there is a page's layout:

```html
<html>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

</html>

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .page {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 90%;
        width: 90%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header slider"
            "content slider";
        grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr;
        gap: 30px;
    }

    .page .header {
        grid-area: header;
    }

    .page .content {
        grid-area: content;
    }

    .page .slider {
        grid-area: slider;
    }

    .page>div {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

likes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j59fu.png)

and then, i fill the content:

```
<html>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

</html>

<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .page {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 90%;
        width: 90%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header slider"
            "content slider";
        grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr;
        gap: 30px;
    }

    .page .header {
        grid-area: header;
    }

    .page .content {
        grid-area: content;
    }

    .page .slider {
        grid-area: slider;
    }

    .page>div {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .page .content .container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: skyblue;
        border: 2px solid rgb(97, 145, 188);
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 2px blue;
    }
</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkEIW.png)

now, the box-shadow is hidden due to .content's `overflow: hidden`(i need set layout have truly height and width, so add `overflow: hidden`)

how can i show the box-shadow? or how to Design a Layout so that Content can Adapt to Shadows without Writing Specific Width and Height?

Comment: If you remove this ```.container``` in this style ```.page .content .container``` , the box shadow will show? Is that it?

Comment: certainly，is actually a React component, and I need a layout as the "framework". After filling in the content, I hope the content can directly fill these grids and serve as a border box to retain its own external shadow